# Is there anyway to bridge between Azure Service Bus queue and a WebSphere queue?

Tags: ibm-mq, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there anyway to bridge between Azure Service Bus queue and a WebSphere queue?

Preferably "something" hosted in Azure, rather than an on-premise product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a wiki page [`How to Send message from an on premise IBM MQ to Azure Service Bus queue`](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-azure/wiki/How-to-Send-message-from-an-on-premise-IBM-MQ-to-Azure-Service-Bus-queue) which introduce for the needs. You can follow it to create a program, either as a continous web job on Azure if using Azure App Service, or running on Azure VM if you want.

If the WebSphere MQ works on network within public IP, I think it's simple without any other additional work for network configuration. If not, you can try to create an [Azure VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/) to establish secure & cross-premises connectivity between them for message transfering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Logic Apps, there are connectors for Azure Service Bus and WebSphere MQ.