# IBM MQ integration with Azure

Tags: azure, ibm-mq, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

Requirement is to consume continuous small XML messages (100 kb) from IBM MQ, read some information and accordingly store the XML file in Azure Storage.

[Is there anyway to bridge between Azure Service Bus queue and a WebSphere queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851965/is-there-anyway-to-bridge-between-azure-service-bus-queue-and-a-websphere-queue)

mentions two approaches 1. WebJob 2. Logic App

My question is which approach  is more suitable considering above requirement and cost.

Answer (score 0):

Both should work, with Logic Apps, you can use the built-in connector to connect to MQ and Service Bus, so it saves you time on integration. The cost really depends on how many such messages you will be processing, with WebJobs you obviously pay 24/7 even if no message need to be processed, whereas Logic Apps is a true pay-as-you-go.

Comment: System is expected to receive approx 5000 messages per day spread across whole day. I think Log App requires  Enterprise Licence to connect to IBM MQ. Which costs approx $1000 per month with 50K actions per day included. 50K action per day should be fine for 5K messages, but $1000 seems will overdo perpetual WebJob

Comment: @SarveshGupta which solution did you use for this use case?